# Extracting features from caffe last layer

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to extract features from the last layer of a GoogleNet caffe model fine-tuned on car classification. Here's the [deploy.prototxt](https://gist.github.com/bogger/b90eb88e31cd745525ae#file-deploy-prototxt). I tried a couple of things:

1. I took features from **'loss3_classifier_model'** layer which is incorrect.
2. Now I am extracting features from **'pool5'** layer in the model as given in prototxt.

I am not sure whether it's correct or not because the features I am extracting for different cars doesn't seem to have much difference. In other words, I am unable to differentiate cars using this last layer features, I used Euclidean distance on features **(Is it correct?)**. I am not using using softmax as I don't want to classify them, I just want features and I rechecking them using euclidean distance.

These are the steps I followed:

```
## load the model 
net = caffe.Net('deploy.prototxt',
                caffe.TEST,
                weights ='googlenet_finetune_web_car_iter_10000.caffemodel') 

# resize the input size as I have only one image in my batch.
net.blobs["data"].reshape(1, 3, 224, 224)

# I read my image of size (x,y,3)
frame = cv2.imread(frame_path) 

bbox = frame[int(x1):int(x2), int(y1):int(y2)] # getting the car, # I have stored x1,x2,x3,x4 seperatly.
# resized my image to 224,224,3, network input size.
bbox = cv2.resize(bbox, (224, 224)) 

# to align my input to the input of the model 
bbox_input = bbox.swapaxes(1,2).reshape(3,224,224) 

# fed input image to the model.
net.blobs['data'].data[0] = bbox_input 
net.forward()

# features from pool5 layer or the last layer.
temp = net.blobs["pool5"].data[0]
```

Now, I want to confirm if these steps are correct or not? I am new to caffe and I am not sure about the steps I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

Both options are valid. **The farther you are from the end of your network, the less specialized the features will be to your problem/training set, while still capturing relevant information that may be applied to similar tasks**. As you move to the end of the network, the features will be more tuned to your task.

Note that you are dealing with two similar problems/tasks. The network was fine-tuned for car classification ("which model is this car?") and now you want to verify if two cars belong to the same model.

Considering the network was fine-tuned with a large and representative training set, the features obtained from it are powerful and with a lot of representation capability (i.e., they capture a lot of complex underlying patterns of the task they were trained to) that are useful to your verification task.

With this in mind, you could try many ways of comparing two feature vectors:

- **Euclidean Distance** is too simple. I would try it only because it is easy/fast to implement;
- **Cosine Similarity** [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) might also be a simple, but good starting point;
- **Classifier**. Another possibility that I've have done in a similar problem was to train a classifier (SVM, Logistic Regression) on top of a combination of the two features. The input of your classifier could be the concatenation of them side by side.
- **Incorporate the verification task to your network**. You could alter the GoogleNet architecture to receive two photos of cars and output if they belong or not to the same model. You would be transforming/fine-tuning your network from the classification problem to a verification task. Check for *siamese networks* [[2]](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/siamese.html).

**Edit**: there is a mistake when you resize your frame that may be the cause of your problems!

```
# I read my image of size (x,y,3)
frame = cv2.imread(frame_path) 

# resized my image to 224,224,3, network input size.
bbox = cv2.resize(frame, (224, 224))
```

You should have passed `frame` as input in the `cv2.resize()` method. You are probably feeding a garbage input to the network and that is why the output ends up always looking similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you explained that I would get rich set of features from the fine-tuned model, I had the same thought. But, when I extracted the features I saw that the Euclidean distance between different cars was not that much while they were completely different (e.g a white sedan and a black SUV), which makes things difficult when I compare 100s of cars. Now, as you pointed out that Euclidean distance might not be a good option, I will try cosine similarity and see. I can't use Siamese network right now because we are kind of testing one method called dominant set.

Comment: Further, the point of issue was that I was not sure about the caffe code I wrote above. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't add one line here, I have changed it above. Originally I have included that in my code. I have re-checked I am giving right image.

Comment: Everything seems to be fine. I'm not sure what may be causing that. Check if the network is classifying the input image correctly (or at least with the same degree of error you were expecting in your testing/validation set). If that happens, then probably only a small change in the feature vectors is able to differentiate the car's model.

Comment: Another thing you could try is to plot a histogram of the euclidean distance (or other distance/similarity you might be using) for same-model and different-model pairs of images across all your dataset. And check how overlaped are these histograms. That might be give you a hint about how these features are behaving in the verification task.